# existence of irreducible representation with character nonzero in an element.

Tags: representation-theory

This is a question from a past exam that I found:
If $G$ is a finite group and $g\in G$, then

(a)there exists at least one irreducible representation of $G$ with character $\chi$ such that $\chi(g)\ne 0$.

(b)If $g\ne 1$, then there exists 2 such irreducible representation.

My solution for (a) is:characters are class functions, and characters of  irreducible representations are basis for the space of class functions. So if I just take a class function taking nonzero value on the conjugacy class of $g$, then it is a linear combination of characters of  irreducible representations, so one of them is nonzero in the conjugacy class of $g$, and it is nonzero on $g$.

But for (b), I want to show that there are at least two in that linear combination that take nonzero value on $g$, but I'm pretty much stuck here.

There is a hint in the problem saying consider the regular representation of $G$, but I can't see how that would help.

Comment: You know that the character of the regular representation has value $0$ on everything except $1$, right?

Answer (score 2):

For (a) use $\chi_1$ the trivial character. For (b), since $g\ne 1$, there are at least two elements in $G$ and at least two irreducible characters. If all of them except $\chi_1$ satisfy $\chi(g)=0$ we have a contradiction because of orthogonality of columns for conjugacy class $1$ and class $g$ of the character table.